# XCode 6 preprocessor directive ( #ifndef ) not working, can't use nested headers

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode

I'm having troubles with nested headers,

#### a.h

```
#ifndef a_h
#define a_h
    #include<b.h>
#endif
```

#### b.h

```
#ifndef b_h
#define b_h
    #include<a.h>
#endif
```

Looks like the include guards are not working.
In fact, I'm getting Apple Mach-O Linker Error, duplicate symbols, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the headers are likely to be included by multiple translation inits. Each one has its own macro definitions. ... and any definition in the headers is duplicated. I'd guess that's the problem rather than `#ifndef` not working.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you have items that shouldn't be *implemented* or *defined* in headers in one (and thus the other) of the above. So what are the duplicate symbols and what is their purpose in your program? Posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that include-guards don't work with an C++ compiler. It is way more likely that your header file(s) contain *definitions* of objects or functions rather than only *declarations* thereof. Without seeing the offending content of the files it is impossible to tell what is the case exactly but most likely you have a setup along those lines:

```
// a.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_A
#define INCLUDED_A
#include "b.h"
int e;
#endif

// b.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_B
#define INCLUDED_B
#include "a.h"
int f() { return 17; }
#endif

// c.cpp
#include "a.h"

// d.cpp
#include "d.h"
```

The problem is that the symbols `e` and `f` are *definitions*. When including the header(s) into a translation unit, e.g., `c.cpp` and `d.cpp`, you'll get them defined in each of the resulting object files. That has *nothing* to do with the include guards: the include guards only affect the completion of one translation unit and, e.g., prevent that the compiler tries to expand them recursively in each of the header files.

Header files cannot contain definitions of objects or functions (unless they are made inline explicitly or implicitly for some reason). Instead, the headers should contain _declarations. For example, these are declaration of `e` and `f`:

```
extern int e;
int f();
```

Note that this is also a definition:

```
extern int f() { return 17; }
```

A function declaration which contains a body is a definition even if the declaration is preceded by the `extern` keyword. On the other hand, every declaration of a function without a body isn't a definition, independent on whether it is preceded by the `extern` keyword.

To fix your problem you need to move the definitions leading to duplicated symbols into a suitable `.cpp` file. I'd define anything declared in `a.h` in the file `a.cpp`.